# Google Authentication via .NET/OWIN: Access_Denied

Tags: oauth, owin, google-authentication

When I try to call Google to authenticate, I get an access_denied response.

I have the Google+ API enabled

This code was working yesterday and I do not see anything that would cause it to break now.

This code works in one environment (dev) but fails in another (test).

I updated our test environment to have the same code (copied from dev) and it fails there.

This seems to be server related, but I can't figure out why.

Google's configuration has all the appropriate response and redirect uris (I just changed the subdomain).

Is there anyway I can find out WHY access is denied?

Comment: It's rather hard to debug your code if you don't show us the code.

Comment: It's all the .NET default code.  I don't think there is anything to debug in code as the exact same code works in prod and dev.  Also the code worked in test a few days ago.  What I'm mainly asking is, is there some way to get more details other than "access_denied" from google.

Comment: Unless .NET is trying, on its own, to ask Google to do something, then showing you this error *without you doing anything*, it's probably your code -- namely, how you're calling it. Please post that. It may well help. 'Course, I don't do much .NET, so I could be dead wrong.

Comment: I guess put another way, what would cause the "access_denied" error

Comment: Giving an expired token of some sort probably would cause the errors you're looking at (works one day, doesn't the next, with no change, and denies access), but it's hard to know what in your code is causing errors when we can't see the code. If it's three lines of basic code, all the better -- it eliminates that as a potential cause for concern. Also, if you show code, it might help find other errors

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for getting a generic access denied error when interacting with Google is their block on "less secure apps": https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

It generally returns an error that is assumed by most apps and sites as an incorrect password, even if your password is correct. If you are using different Google accounts between dev and test, and one is configured differently than the other, this might be a possible reason.

Comment: Interesting.  But I am using the same account in dev and test.